# Scrolling in Firefox as in Nautilus

Tags: firefox, scrolling

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 on a laptop. Is it possible to make scrolling with touchpad behave the same way in firefox as it does in nautilus?
If you don't know what I mean, it's the scrolling without these steps. Instead it seems to be pixel by pixel.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Firefox scrolls smoothly (even with a mouse wheel) for me. What's your hardware, PC model, etc? Maybe it's an add-on/extension causing problems?

Comment: I'm on a Dell Vostro 3750. I think it uses the ALPS driver. Exact Specs: Intel Core i5-2450M @ 4x2.5GhZ, 4GB RAM, onboard graphics card

Comment: I only have 2 addons installed: Adblock Plus and Proxmate. It's not the "smooth scrolling" option that I want, it does that for me. What I'd like to have is touchscreen-like behaviour. The same way as scrolling with two fingers in Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your hardware; if your mouse supports smooth scrolling wheels it works...

BUT: Here is a trick to get perfect smooth scrolling in Firefox (just like safari)

1. Obvious: make sure smooth scrolling is enabled in the Firefox settings (as well as HW acceleration)
2. Set your vm.swappiness=0.  Sounds strange I know but because the smoothness of the least amount of memory swapping, setting sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0 will actually smooth out the Firefox scrolling with amazing effectiveness. To make it permanent type in the console: sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf  and add a line  vm.swappiness=1  to the bottom of the file and save. (restart and you are done)